# How do I appease the borrow checker with nested data structures?

Tags: rust, binary-tree, borrow-checker

I'm working on a (rather ambitious) text editor, and I'm trying to implement arbitrary vertical and horizontal splits to display text buffers in, something like this:

```
     buffer
-----------------
buffer |
-------|  buffer
buffer |
```

I have this structure represented as a binary tree-type thing:

```
    h
   / \
  v   b
 / \
b   h
   / \
  b   b
```

where `v` is a vertical split, `h` is a horizontal split, and `b` is a buffer.

In code form, it is this:

```
pub enum LayoutNode {
    Buf(Buffer),
    Split(Box<Split>),
}

pub enum Split {
    Vertical(LayoutNode, LayoutNode),
    Horizontal(LayoutNode, LayoutNode)
}

pub struct Buffer {
    content: String,
    // more buffer-related stuff
}
```

All is well. My vertical split method:

```
impl LayoutNode {
    pub fn vertical_split(layout: LayoutNode) -> LayoutNode {
        LayoutNode::Split(Box::new(Split::Vertical(layout, LayoutNode::Buf(Buffer::new()))))
        // Buffer::new() returns an empty Buffer
    }
}
```

This function compiles, but is not the whole story. I have a data structure responsible for the editor's layout nodes, called `Editor`:

```
impl Editor {
    pub fn new() -> Editor {
        Editor {
            buffers: LayoutNode::Buf(Buffer::empty()),
            // more editor-related stuff
        }
    }

    pub fn vertical_split(&mut self) {
        // buffers needs to be a part of itself
        self.buffers = LayoutNode::vertical_split(self.buffers);
        // cannot move out of borrowed content    ^
    }
}
```

I've taken a look at `mem::replace` but I'm not sure that it's what I need for this case with nested data structures. The `rustc --explain` page for `E0507` isn't very helpful in this regard.

How do I work with the borrow checker in this case? I'd rather not clone everything, since that will easily waste a lot of memory with a new copy of every file upon each split.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mem::replace` is often used in situations like this to set the field to a dummy, but valid value while you're producing the new value. This is necessary to ensure that if the thread panics while producing the new value, the destructor will not free the same objects twice.

In your case, it might look something like this:

```
impl Editor {
    pub fn new() -> Editor {
        Editor {
            buffers: LayoutNode::Buf(Buffer::empty()),
        }
    }

    pub fn vertical_split(&mut self) {
        // buffers needs to be a part of itself
        self.buffers = LayoutNode::vertical_split(
            mem::replace(&mut self.buffers, LayoutNode::Buf(Buffer::empty())));
    }
}
```

It works like this: `mem::replace` receives a mutable reference to the variable or field to replace and the value to assign, and returns the old value. You get ownership of the result, so you can move it freely.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, the value assigned to `self.buffers` using `mem::replace` is thrown away once it gets assigned to using `vertical_split`? If I wanted to prevent memory wasting, could I add an empty variant to `LayoutNode`?

Comment: Yes, the value moved into `self.buffers` by `mem::replace` will be overwritten when the assignment is performed once `vertical_split` returns. And yes, if `Buffer::empty()` is "expensive", you might want to add an empty variant to `LayoutNode`, but then every match on that type will have to "handle" it (which can be as simple as coding it as `unreachable!()`).